# Does IndexedDB support partial updates?

Tags: indexeddb

I know MongoDB support [$set operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/). Is there a similar way in IndexedDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indexedDB does not support partial updates. You either overwrite an entire object, or you do not.